# How can I bypass IE's popup blocker so my JavaScript popup works?

Tags: javascript

I have to open a new window

```
window.open();
```

But in IE, it will detects a popup and block, if I allow then the window is opened.

How can I bypass this popup blocker and open it directly?

Comment: BUMP! Do you plan on assigning the answer to anyone? All you have to do is click the checkmark next to the best answer. As a side note, why don't you just ask the user to manually disable the popup blocker on their computer if it is so important? I know a lot of sites that still use popups. The popups are blocked, but then a little bar comes up asking me if I want to allow popups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't bypass any good popup blocker. The reason why it is called a popup blocker is because it blocks popups.

Comment: jquery popupWindow , What anything like that with mootool ?

Comment: jQuery/mootools can't do it either. If you really need a popup, the most honest way would be to make a Link to open a page in a new window (target="_blank" attribute). Sometimes, you can also make flash popup windows, which can bypass weak browser popup blockers.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to a popup window would be to use a modal dialog. There are many jQuery options available, take a look:

- [jQuery UI modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)
- [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)
- [Facebox](http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/)

Comment: i don't want to something like modal, it only open a window, i want to open more window when user click at time , user can see and compare

Comment: are you opening up links to other sites or pages within your own site?

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to open the popup? If it is through a user click I guess it shouldn't be a problem, unless you are using 3rd-party tools to block popups.

Although if you are trying to open on a `mouse` event or `load` event you will not be able to without user consent.

Comment: users will only click on link when they need, and i want to pass popup blocker,

Answer (score -1):

Most browsers will not block a popup when you click a link, provided that the popup window is on the **same domain**.

If it's a cross site popup, it **will** be blocked, and you **cannot** stop it. Even attempting to bypass it in that case is black hat.